# What is the difference between the two Google JS clients: platform.js vs api.js?

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

```
A) <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
```

versus

```
B) <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
```

I am a little bit confused about how to use Google OAuth service, should I use **platform** script or **api** script.

Answer (score 2):

The functionality in platform.js is a superset of the functionality in api.js. If you are using both the sheets APIs and the sign-in API, platform.js will suffice, you needn't load both. ~[https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/issues/658](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/issues/658#issuecomment-692839901)

platform.js is a platform detection library that works on nearly all JavaScript platforms.
platform.js is for informational purposes only & not intended as a substitution for feature detection/inference checks.
platform.js is Google's library for accessing the Google Plus API.

Platform.js is part of the BestieJS “Best in Class” module collection. This means we promote solid browser/environment support, ES5+ precedents, unit testing, & plenty of documentation.

Using the platform.js library, it becomes very easy for us to detect the browser just by writing one line of JavaScript code. You can get this library on GitHub. All the complicated code is already written in this library and we just have to use it.

Answer (score 0):

[The answer of Neha Jha](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65939233/1323473) is right for your question, however, I wanna update the news from Google. They announce to [discontinue Google Sign-In JavaScript Platform Library for web](https://developers.googleblog.com/2021/08/gsi-jsweb-deprecation.html) and **they ask us to migrate to the new thing before 31/03/2023**.

Answer (score -2):

**platform.js** is the Google Plus API, **which has been shut down march 7th 2019**.

**api.js** is the [Google API Client Library for JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/) "The Google API Client Library for JavaScript is designed for JavaScript client-application developers. It offers simple, flexible access to many Google APIs."

Use api.js for your use case. See [this](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/authentication).

Comment: This doesn't seem accurate. The Google Sign-In library docs (https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in) still prescribe using platform.js: "You must include the Google Platform Library on your web pages that integrate Google Sign-In."

Comment: @sowee15 Where did you hear platform.js had been shutdown on March 7? I've found that they still reference it in a lot of links? Depration notice: (https://developers.google.com/+/api-shutdown) directs developers to migrate to (https://developers.google.com/identity/) which then has a web link to (https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/) which still references (platform.js) in their example. BHSPitMonkey reference also shows an example with platform.js